# What preposition goes with "audiovisual media"

Tags: prepositions

As in the sentence *I create content to be displayed [in/on] audiovisual media.*

Comment: Something to think about: prepositions don't go with objects, they go with the verbs, too. _We ate lunch **at** the beach. We will run **to** the beach. Towels were strewn **across** the beach_. You might also appreciate [ell.se].

Comment: @J.R. Isn't there a 'just' missing? Both the verb and the prepositional object inform the choice of preposition.

Comment: ... *via* audiovisual media."

Comment: @J.R. I'm not sure I agree, sometimes we use a specific preposition just because of the noun that goes with it, e.g. _I'm **on** Facebook, I've heard it **on** the radio_, and so on. I'll probably use "via". Thank you all!

Comment: @Anglophile - I agree, sometimes we do – but sometimes we don't. Incidentally, in this case, either _on_ or _in_ would sound better to me than _via_.

Comment: ***in, on, through, with, using, via, by,...*** - it's just a ***stylistic choice***.

Comment: @Anglophile: There are plenty of written instances of *[He] heard it [**over**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22heard+it+over+the+radio%22) / [**from**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22heard+it+from+the+radio%22) / [**via**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22heard+it+via+the+radio%22) / [**through**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22heard+it+through+the+radio%22) / ... the radio.* Prepositions are *very* flexible in English. And the verb *does* matter - *He **learned** it **on** the radio* is "weird" compared to ***...through / over / from** the radio*.

Comment: Come on now, folks: **I create content for audiovisual media**. To be displayed is wrong here.There is zero justification for it. This question is editing....Ergo, the question is misguided. Prepositions have nothing doing here.

Answer (score -1):

Delivery is the act of moving produced goods from producer to consumer.  So the context is delivery.  You want the audiovisual media to deliver your content.  The preposition for delivery is *via*:

> I create content to be displayed *via* audiovisual media.

This being said @Ringo isn't wrong and if where the media goes in the A/V device is important, or you are really putting media on the surface of the device, *in* or *on* may be better.

Answer (score -2):

I would say ***in***. You are creating content that is inserted into the media --
 or imported into the media -- be it film or audio track. ***On***, while not grammatically incorrect, implies that you're somehow superimposing your content onto the surface of the media. Or attaching content to the outside of it. In actuality, you are contributing to the media by putting your creativity into it. I think ***in*** is more appropriate.

Perhaps an argument for ***on*** would be if you created subtitles for films, or if you literally draw or paint on film cells.

Comment: I was going to answer with "through", but [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=through+audiovisual+media%2Cin+audiovisual+media%2Con+audiovisual+media&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthrough%20audiovisual%20media%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20audiovisual%20media%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20audiovisual%20media%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthrough%20audiovisual%20media%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20audiovisual%20media%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20audiovisual%20media%3B%2Cc0) seem to support "in".

Comment: @Davo Literally, "media" means the means by which the content is delivered, but it's often used to refer to the content itself. "Through" makes sense for the former.